# Internal Server Error When POST to Marketing Cloud Asset REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel-sdk

I am getting an internal server error when trying to save an asset to the content library.

```
let options = {
  uri: '/asset/v1/content/assets',
  json: true,
  body: MCData
}

const RestClient = new FuelRest({auth: FuelAuthClient});
RestClient.post(options)
.then((result) => {
  console.dir(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.dir(error);
})
```

The body of my request (MCData) is:

```
{
  "name":"Document 123",
  "assetType":{
    "name":"png",
    "id":28
  },
  "file":"data:image/png;base64, REST OF THE Encoded IMAGE HERE"
}
```

I can make a get request to the same endpoint (https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets) and retrieve that I have no content (a correct response with a count of zero).

I am using the [FuelSDK-Node-REST library](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-REST). Error is

```
{ message: 'Internal Server Error',
 errorcode: 0,
 documentation: 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm' }
```

Comment: My gut feel (which is not an answer) is that you're missing some stuff...the data part of the body comes to mind.  Make sure to go through the asset reference guide at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset-model.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a stupidly simple solution that followed from looking at Timothy's link. I noticed the file in that link had no file type (which MC must be deriving from the Asset Type being created) so I split the Base64 string around the ',' to remove the **data:image/png;base64,** and retried with success.